# Programmatically exit Backstage View

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-2013

We have a [backstage extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833.aspx) that [integrates with the `TabSave` idMso](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2013/04/05/customizing-office-2013-backstage.aspx) (*File-->SaveAs*).

The issue we're having is that when I click a button from the backstage - I don't know how to close the backstage view.

The best solution I've come up with isn't very robust, so I was hoping someone would have a better approach for dealing with this as it seems fairly intuitive to close the backstage view. Maybe I'm missing something - but I can't get the backstage view to exit once my button fires.

#### Ribbon XML

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <backstage>
        <tab idMso="TabSave">
            <firstColumn>
                <taskFormGroup idMso="SaveGroup">
                    <category idMso="Save">
                        <task id="customTask" label="Custom Task" imageMso="HappyFace">
                            <group id="customGroup1" label="Custom Group">
                                <topItems>
                                    <labelControl id="lblInfo" label="Click to trigger custom action."/>
                                    <button id="btnCustomAction" style="large" label="Custom Action" imageMso="HappyFace" onAction="btnAction"/>
                                </topItems>
                            </group>
                        </task>
                    </category>
                </taskFormGroup>
            </firstColumn>
        </tab>
    </backstage>
</customUI>
```

#### Ribbon Callbacks

```cs
public void btnAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
   Excel.Window window = control.Context;
   MessageBox.Show("custom action triggered");
   window.Application.SendKeys("{ESCAPE}");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the solution is [not publicized well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634163%28v=office.14%29.aspx) - there's a flag (*`isDefinitive`*) on the button that automatically closes the backstage view once the button is clicked - not when the action completes.

```xml
<button id="btnCustomAction" 
        style="large" 
        label="Custom Action" 
        imageMso="HappyFace" 
        isDefinitive="true"
        onAction="btnAction"/>
```

#### [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634163%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> Closing the Backstage view and returning to the current workbook
>   occurs by setting the control's `isDefinitive` attribute in the
>   custom UI XML.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI.ActivateTab("SomeControlIdOfARibbonTab")
```

Regards, Jörg